# Regex/sed formatting help for upload to sheets

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Hello I am looking for some help on how to format a file using sed.

I have a file that is generated that looks something like this:

```
projectA
email1@demo.com
Email2@test.com
email3@demoA.com
TestB
testUser@demo.com
email4@test.com
ProjectC
email1@demo.com
```

I was playing around with sed to format, but I know there is an easier way to go about this instead of running several sed commands.

I'd like for the format to Look something like this in sheets:

```
ProjectID1 | Email1 | Email2 | ...
ProjectID2 | Email1 | Email2 | Email3 | ...
ProjectID3 | Email1 | ...
```

Comment: awk would probably be better than sed...

Comment: Does this do what you wanted: `sed -n '/@/H;/@/!{x;s/\n/|/g;p};${x;s/\n/|/g;p}' file.txt`  (I got the idea from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309129/technique-to-concatenate-groups-of-consecutive-lines-delimited-by-pattern)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Nice. And if you add `1!` before the first `p` command you avoid the leading empty line.

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
projectA
email1@demo.com
Email2@test.com
email3@demoA.com
TestB
testUser@demo.com
email4@test.com
ProjectC
email1@demo.com
```

then

```
awk 'NR>1{printf /@/?" | ":"\n"}{printf $0}' file.txt
```

output

```
projectA | email1@demo.com | Email2@test.com | email3@demoA.com
TestB | testUser@demo.com | email4@test.com
ProjectC | email1@demo.com
```

Assumption: every line with `@` anywhere is email, every other line is project id.

Explanation: I use `printf` as it does not add newline to end. Before all but first line I `printf` either `|` or newline (`\n`) depending if it is mail line or other line, I use ternary operator (condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse) to select depending on if line contains `@` or not. For every line I `printf` it. Note: my code produce output without trailing newline, if you does need one then add `END{print ""}` behind `{printf $0}`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n(.*@)/ | \1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Gather up lines, replacing the newline between lines which are not email addresses and lines that are email addresses by `|`.